# Infinite Recursion with Jackson

Tags: json, hibernate, jackson

I'm having problems with Jackson 1.6.3 and Hibernate. I found this thread here : [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

But it did not solve the problem.

I have a Node object that has incoming and outgoing relations. Even with the @JsonManagedReference annotations, on the console of the app server I can see the exceptions being thrown (infinite recursion).

Is there any alternative to that?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="nodes")
public class Node implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

@Column(name="x_pos")
private double x;


@Column(name="y_pos")
private double y;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="source")
@JsonManagedReference("outgoingRelations")
private Set<Relation> outgoingRelations;


@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="target")
@JsonManagedReference("incomingRelations")
private Set<Relation> incomingRelations;



@Entity
@Table(name="relations")
public class Relation implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="source")
@JsonBackReference("outgoingRelations")
private Node source;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="target")
@JsonBackReference("incomingRelations")
private Node target;
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

From [spring - Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue):

> You may use [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) to break the cycle.

Comment: Except it doesn't work with Hibernate 4.2.2 and javassist objects and Hibernate internal lists.

Comment: Hello, is there another way to solve this? @JsonIgnore does not work anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can try to break the loop either at Node end or at Relation by following 3 ways

- Use @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference
- Use @JsonIdentityInfo
- Use @JsonIgnore

**Use @JsonIdentityInfo**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "nodes")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(
              generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
              property = "id")
    public class Node {
        ...
    }
    
    
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "relations")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(
              generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
              property = "id")
    public class Relation {
        ...
    }
```

**Use @JsonIgnore**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="node")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Node> lstNode;
```

**Refer more in detail [here](https://ashishontech.xyz/jackson-json-infinite-recursion-problem/) with the working demo as well.**